# Javascript unable to convert timestamp to date

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im using this function

```
export const getDate = (stamp: string) => {
    console.log(stamp) //1581638400000
    let date : any = Date.parse(stamp)
    console.log(date) //NaN
    let month = date.getMonth()
    let day = date.getDay()
    let year = date.getYear()

    let formattedTime = month + '/' + day + '/' + year
    return formattedTime
}
```

But it seems to work fine in this site

[image]

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Whats the deal? Why cant i use that stamp ?

Comment: [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) expects a string representation. If you want to create a date from a timestamp, use `new Date(stamp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `new Date()`. [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) expect a string representation and you seem to give it a number.

Furthermore you are getting a bad formatted date:

[`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week, number between 0 to 6. Use [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) instead, returns a number between 1 to 31.

[`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) starts from 0.

[`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) is deprecated use [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) instead.

see the following:

```js
const getDate = (stamp) => {
  console.log(stamp);
  let date = new Date(stamp);
  console.log(date);
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let day = date.getDate();
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let formattedTime = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
  return formattedTime;
}

console.log(getDate(1581638400000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let stamp = "1581638400000"
const getDate = (stamp) => {
    console.log(new Date(Number(stamp))) ;//1581638400000
    let date = new Date(Number(stamp));
    console.log(date); //NaN
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let day = date.getDay();
    // let year = date.getYear(); Deprecated!!!
    let year = date.getFullYear();

    let formattedTime = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    console.log(formattedTime);
    return formattedTime;
}

getDate(stamp)
```

Comment: 120 makes no sense , it should be 20

Comment: Yesss! It is [Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) ; )

Comment: Alternative `let year = date.getFullYear()`;

Answer (score -1):

```
var date = new Date(stamp * 1000);  // * 1000 if you want milliseconds
```

Comment: 1581638400000 is  already in milliseconds